# Referencing cells with hyperlinks in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with references to a column in another sheet which has user input URLS (all within the same spreadsheet).

On the source sheet, the URLs appear as individual, clickable URLs.
By using ALT-ENTER, we can use multiline input to store many URLs

On the destination sheet, it just references the column, and some URLs show up as clickable and some dont. Is this a formatting issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the destination is really on another sheet or another spreadsheet?

Comment: If I try what you describe on the same spreadsheet, with different sheets, it works (i.e. the formatting is the same and the reference to another column gives a clickable link).

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it's a formatting issue.

However, when I tried to reproduce what you describe I found that my cells generated the clickable hyperlinks automatically.

That is, the cell `Sheet1!A1` was `"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67763194/referencing-cells-with-hyperlinks-in-google-sheets`" and Sheet2!A1 was `=Sheet1!A1`, which generated the clickable link.

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be an option to format a cell as a "link cell" without explicitly using the formula `=HYPERLINK()`.

A workaround is to copy a cell with a generated link and paste formatting across those cells where it's desired (which works for multiple cells) or to use the "insert link" option <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> on Windows or Chrome (or <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> on Mac) if only for a few cells.